# Как зафиксировать views на layout, чтобы верстка не поехала на разных экранах?

Tags: android, android-textview, android-button

Как разместить на весь экран `TextView`, а в самом низу `Button`?

`TextView` должен находится внутри `ScrollView`, а `Button` не должна перекрывать `TextView`.

Какой лучше использовать корневой елемент для этой цели?

Вот что уже есть, но кнопка перекрывает `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:gravity="top">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EMPTY"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Read" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать **weight** Это атрибут макета **LinearLayout**. Будет работать на всех экранах. Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Суть веса в том, что если на экране остается свободное место, всем view, у которых есть атрибут **weight**, раздается оставшееся место по вертикали или горизонтали (в зависимости от того, какая ориентация у макета). То есть в данном примере *70% - на **ScrollView***, *30% - на **Button***.

---

P.S. *Сумма атрибутов **weight** необязательно должна равняться 10. Можете выбрать хоть 100, хоть 1000.*

Comment: Спасибо. С весом даже код стал меньше. Я применил вес только к `ScrollView` и он занял все свободное пространство и при этом не лезет под `Button`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно по разному. Например, можно указать `scrollView` быть над кнопкой через атрибут `android:layout_above`

Таким образом разметка будет такова:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_abovу="@id/readBtn"
        android:gravity="top">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EMPTY"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Read" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Но я выбрал решение с весом, так как это уменьшает количество кода.

Comment: @AnatolySamokisha, не вопрос)